# Push a nested json array

Tags: json, google-apps-script, nested-lists

Om hopping fore your help.
Im trying to push objekt wihtin a nested json array.

The json-input looks like this:

```
"result":[{"MyEnergyData_MarketDocument":{"mRID":"8000cfdc-0000-f600-b63f-84710c7967bb","createdDateTime":"2022-11-03T08:15:18Z","sender_MarketParticipantname":"","sender_MarketParticipant.mRID":{"codingScheme":null,"name":null},"period.timeInterval":{"start":"2022-06-30T22:00:00Z","end":"2022-07-04T22:00:00Z"},"TimeSeries":[{"mRID":"571313181100574632","businessType":"A04","curveType":"A01","measurement_Unit.name":"KWH","MarketEvaluationPoint":{"mRID":{"codingScheme":"A10","name":"571313181100574632"}},"Period":[{"resolution":"PT1H","timeInterval":{"start":"2022-06-30T22:00:00Z","end":"2022-07-01T22:00:00Z"},"Point":[{"position":"1","out_Quantity.quantity":"0.489","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"},{"position":"2","out_Quantity.quantity":"7.57","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"},{"position":"3","out_Quantity.quantity":"0.131","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"}
```

The Google Script looks like this:

```
var meterdatajson = Utilities.jsonParse(meterdata);
var meterdataArray = meterdatajson['result'];
var arrayProperties = [];
    meterdataArray.forEach(function(el) {
      arrayProperties.push([el.???????],
         );});
```

I tried everything, but cant g’et a hold on “start”, “position” and “out_Quantity.quintity”

I tried many different strings inside the function(el)

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate the nested objects. For example:

```
el.MyEnergyData_MarketDocument.TimeSeries[0].Period[0].Point[0].position
```

That would give you "1".
So your full loop would be something like this:

```
meterdataArray.forEach(function(el) {
  arrayProperties.push(
    el.MyEnergyData_MarketDocument.TimeSeries[0].Period[0].Point.map(p => [
      p.position,
      p.out_Quantity.quantity
    ])
  );
});
```

That will give you an array of arrays of [position, quantity] pairs for the first TimeSeries/Period.

Comment: Thank you for takling the time to answer.
2 things.
out_Quantity.quantity fails, I suspekt the “.”
TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined

Second: I only g’et the first 24 entries of position, because it backs ud aften that.
{"position":"23","out_Quantity.quantity":"0.167","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"},{"position":"24","out_Quantity.quantity":"0.127","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"}]},{"resolution":"PT1H","timeInterval":{"start":"2022-07-01T22:00:00Z","end":"2022-07-02T22:00:00Z"},"Point":[{"position":"1","out_Quantity.quantity":"0.136","out_Quantity.quality":"A04"},

Comment: The “.” in out_Quantity.quantity is denoting a nested property, so you'll need to access it like this:

` el.out_Quantity.quantity`

This assumes that el has a out_Quantity property which is an object with a quantity property. If this is not the case, that would explain the TypeError you're seeing.
Regarding the truncation of results, it's likely that you have more data than can fit in the Apps Script execution limit. You'll need to use a iterative approach (like forEach) to process the data in batches.

Comment: Im still new. Why did I g’et negative rating?